# Integer and String Array Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How would I do this with an array of ints:

- Get max/min
- Numerically (Ascending)

And for an array of strings:

- Alphabetically

This is the code I have to get an input and sort it to an int array, and for strings obviously I remove the parsing:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] arrayInput = in.nextLine().split("\\s");
int[] arrayParsed = new int[arrayInput.length];

for (int x = 0; x < arrayInput.length; x++) {
    arrayParsed[x] = Integer.parseInt(arrayInput[x]);
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at sorting and getting the max and min?

Comment: `This is the code I have to get an input and sort it to an int array` I don't see sorting in your code. Also you in your `for` loop you can add code to find min/max (but since you are going to sort it anyway then maybe you can skip it). What you are showing us now is just getting data from user.

Comment: I attempted to write a flowchart for the sorting, but I could only figure it out with creating a whole bunch of new variables, which I know isn't the best way.

Comment: go look at Arrays.sort http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: see [Wikipedia: Sorting Algoritms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for some ideas

Comment: There are so many sorting algorithms and implementations on this site and greater Web. Have you even tried to research?

Comment: I did a similar assignment in Ruby a few weeks back, and I found that the easiest way to sort through the array for the min and/or max values was to use a for loop where if the index is larger than a variable (set at the beginning as 0), it sets that variable to the index, and so on. By the end, you should have the largest value. The same for minimum, except the set variable would be something higher than the largest possible value of any index.

Comment: @PM77-1 This isn't homework, it's independent learning.

Comment: Then do your own research and do not skip any steps. Your "*I attempted to write a flowchart for the sorting, but I could only figure it out with creating a whole bunch of new variables*" sounds as I couldn't do it in 5 min, so show me the answer.

Comment: @PM77-1 Then don't bother commenting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort an array:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayParsed);
```

min: 
`arrayParsed[0];`
max: 
 `arrayParsed[arrayParsed.length - 1];`

Comment: Min and max as the highest and lowest values, not the first and last entries.

Comment: @ModifyYou think about it after you sort array.

Comment: Once the array is sorted, the minimum is the first value in your array and the max is your last value in the array.

Comment: Sorting then retrieving the max and min in this manner saves a lot of computation.